# Link Safari's search field to Google's input field?

Tags: mac, safari

I recently switched from Firefox 3.5 to Safari 4 (with glims). The one thing I miss: Coherent searching. In Firefox, I could do this:

1. Type "compiler" in the browser's search field (upper right)
2. See the search results at Google
3. Edit the query, on the Google page, to read "compiler -windows -xp"
4. Press ENTER
5. The browser's copy of the search query gets updated to read "compiler -windows -xp" as well.

I think this might have been done by the Google Toolbar or another extension. But Safari, even with glims, doesn't do this.

I can't seem to retrain myself to edit the search query in the browser.  Safari has the terrific "Search snapback" feature, but I can never use it, because it snaps back to the unedited search query. Is there any add-on that will sync the two fields for me?

Comment: http://www.usingmac.com/2008/4/29/safari-and-firefox-quick-google-search

Comment: @joe: The question was not “How do I search using Google.”

Comment: True! As anyone knows, the answer to THAT question is http://letmegooglethatforyou.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Slightly Longer Answer: You could try searching history as a way to get back to the modified query you made within the google page. Ultimately I think you will just need to get used to making changes to your query within the browser so that you can take full advantage of the browser search integration in Safari.

[image]

Additional Food for Thought: You might check out [Inquisitor](http://www.inquisitorx.com/safari/index_en.php) or [Safari Stand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) both old school safari plugins that have some additional functionality to offer with regards to Safari search (I think Stand might give you some better options for searching through history).  You might find some hooks to better replicate your search workflow.

Final Caveat: I'm not sure Inquisitor is up to date with the latest build of safari and it may give you some trouble with the default google suggestions coming from safari.